# How do I attach a jQuery event to a object's method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I defined an object with properties and methods. But I can't find how to attach a jQuery function to a method. What I want is : when I click on the object #myTarget change its html text.

I wrote this :

```js
function blockTest(word){
 this.word = ""+genRandInt(0, 25); 
 this.applyNewWord = function(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myTarget").click(function(){
    $("#myTarget").html(this.word);  
   });
  });
 };
}
```

Actually, I'm trying to

Comment: The real question is, why on earth would you put an event handler inside a function like that at all, you generally don't want to attach multiple click events to the same element anyway, and even stranger is the DOM ready handler. I think you're simply just doing this wrong.

Comment: @adeneo, what he probably *actually* wants is to store `$("#myTarget").html(this.word)` as a method & bind it to DOM on load.. Anyway, that's the only explanation that makes sense that I see..

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @adeneo I'm new to OOP and jQuery, and obviously, I'm wrong. I just want to know how to this or just if it is possible. Tyblitz understood what I wanted to do. Perhaps, my question was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Accomplishing what you want based on the code you provided isn't the way to go. I'd first create an `Object` rather than using a function. Insert your attributes inside that object and handle your DOM events separately:

```js
(function($) {
   var obj = {
     word: "Example Word",
     applyNewWord: function() {
       return this.word;
     }
   }
   
   $(function() {
     $("#myTarget").on("click", function() {
       $(this).text(obj.applyNewWord())
     });
   });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTarget">Dummy Text</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function blockTest(word){
    var self = this;
    self.word = ""+genRandInt(0, 25);   
    self.applyNewWord = function(){

            $("#myTarget").click(function(){
                $(this).html(self.word);        
            });

    };
}
```

make copy of this and don't keep `document.ready` inside function